# How to take a snapshot of iPhone Home Screen programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When users tap on my app Icon, I would like to take a snapshot of the iPhone Home Screen just before my application is launched, much the same way iOS4 system does that before it puts an app to background mode. (I like to know exact center XY location of my app Icon as well.)

Is it possible?

Following code doesn't work.
By the time, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called the Home Screen is already gone.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.frame.size);
    [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil); // for debugging purpose
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to capture anything outside of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be the bearer of Bad news but it Does seem that would be a Privacy Issue.

Many Blogs and So on in the World of internet have talked about this and have all shook-en their head "NO".

Sorry but this is a task that we are unable to do with the iphone at this current time.